# Excel Grid for my asp.net application

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Can any body give me better tool to use Excel Grid for my asp.net application.

I wanted to have Edit the column like excel..and paste the columns directly in to the grid.

Same like excel features.

Thanks

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/try/try-office-2010-FX101868838.aspx

Comment: thanks hunter, Iam asking to use in my asp.net mvc application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the best (free) i can think of is Telerik Grid (which allows you to edit in line).

see [Telerik Grid Demo here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid)

Comment: That's true, but I dont have copy option in telerik Grid? how to copy the columns in to the grid same like excel.

Comment: i dont think they have it out of the box, you will need to some tuning, maybe have right click action or button to paste from the clipboard